# Can Content Providers fetch data from other devices?

Tags: android, android-room, android-contentprovider

I have 2 phones: Phone A and Phone B. Each Phone has a SEARCH that can query all users that sign up on said phone. I want my SEARCH to query all entries from PHONE A and Phone B not just Phone A.

I am using ROOM which is a local database. Can Content Providers allow me to fetch data from multiple devices?

Answer (score 0):

*Content Providers Content providers can help an application manage access to data stored by itself, stored by other applications, and provide a way to share data with other applications. They encapsulate data and provide mechanisms to define data security. Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process. Implementing a content provider has many advantages.*

> Can content providers allow me to fetch data from multiple devices?

According to the text, yes, the content provider can allow you. if you want more details the https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics?hl=en-us website will offer you more details...

Sorry, it was my friend who was using my email